# React Router - passing Slug as a prop to child Component

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, react-router, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to create the possibility for a page to display itself so long as the data is there - I'm using WordPress REST API and the end user will be able to create pages for themselves that obviously won't appear in the Router as I can't possibly forsee all of the pages they will eventually want to create.

The way I'm trying to resolve this is to pass something of a wildcard into react-router (picture 1).

Picture 1:
[image: Picture 1]

So, in my understanding, if the user visited my site and put in `/giraffe`, it would take them to the `<About />` component, and would put `/giraffe` in the `pageSlug` parameter. However, it puts `:slug` in that parameter.

When I use the React Dev Tools, I can see that there is an element between my `<App />` (top level) component and my `<About />` component with no name and has parameters - see Picture 2:

[image: Picture 2]

This has a component with the following information `<component location={pathname: "/giraffe", search: "", hash: ""} params={slug: "giraffe"} />` etc. Is there any way that I can pass these params into the route?

Here is how I am returning my `<About />` component - Picture 3:

[image: Picture 3]

This is the first time I've used React and React-Router, so I appreciate that this may be a stupid question or I may be doing this all wrong, however I've been trawling through questions and answers for a few hours and am none the wiser. I feel like I should be able to access those parameters, but no idea.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#route-components):

> A route's component is rendered when that route matches the URL. The router will inject the following properties into your component when it's rendered.
>
> #### params
>
> The dynamic segments of the URL.

So if your route is defined as follows:

```
<Route path="/:slug" component={About} />
```

you could access `this.props.params.slug` to get the parameter value.

Comment: Thank you, it seems I was trying to overcomplicate matters.